# Insert a google map in a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I'm new to wordpress and am trying to insert a Google map in a page.

I found tutorials for including a map using the "link" functionality on maps.google, but I want to load specific markers, defined in an xml file.

Do I need a plugin to do that ?

Comment: If wordpress allows you to embed JavaScript in your posts then you can embed a functional google map, and yes, you can load data from the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you could do is create a page template file for your custom code..

ie:

make a copy of page.php open it up in your editor, and paste this at the top of the page before the get_header;

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: CustomMapPage
*/
?>
```

then after you do this & upload it, go back to your wordpress admin, the page you are trying to add the map to (reload/refresh that page) and on the right sidebar select from teh dropdown for template and assign it the value of 'CustomMapPage' then update your page,

Now your using a page template in which you can add code to, which will generate your map,

in your template page add your google api key and any other javascript files you need, 
then following a tutorial like [this](http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/reading-xml-files-with-the-google-maps-api/) or a plugin like [this](http://www.matusz.ch/blog/projekte/xml-google-maps-wordpress-plugin-en/)